# Enterprise OTA app disappears after install

Tags: ios

When distributing an iOS app for a client using the "Enterprise Distribution" option, the app downloads and installs but then quickly disappears from the home screen.  After rebooting the iOS device, it reappears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my situation I actually just reuse the .plist file between builds that is generated if you were to click the "Save for Enterprise Distribution" checkbox when you are about to save the .ipa file. The value I had typed in for the "bundle-identifier" key had an old APPID instead of the one the app is currently distributed under. Correcting this error and reinstalling the app from our website fixed the problem.

Essentially adding a missing *.app.* to our bundle-identifier allowed the application to install properly and stay on the homes creen without need for reboot.

from:

```
<key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.mycompany.MyApp</string>
```

to:

```
<key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.mycompany.app.MyApp</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ThaDon Thanks!  I upvoted you for this post.  I had a similar problem.  I had a plist which I reused from someone else and didn't pay careful enough attention to the value I put in for the bundle-identifier (the previous person used just the app name as the bundle identifier, but I used the recommended reverse domain notation com.. .  It worked fine on iOS 6, but on iOS 5 it downloaded/installed and then disappeared, as you described.  Once I put the exact same bundle identifier I had in my Xcode project, it worked the way I expected it to.